# File with broken permissions on Ubuntu WSL, can't delete but can access

Tags: file, permissions, file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file, `names.txt`. This has always been its name, no special characters or anything. I moved an old version of the file from a zip to replace it, and everything went downhill from there. First, no permissions. So I did a chown. It shows up in the `ls -lb` as exactly what I'd expect.

`-rwxrwxrwx 0 [me] [me] 5 Dec 30 09:28 names.txt`

Except for that 0 after the permissions. I've never seen that before. It used to be 26kB in size but I was able to write "hello" to it in Python, and `cat` reads it back fine. Problem is, I want it gone. And `rm` can't seem to find it. Even doing the `rm -i -- *` trick to have it ask me for each file it sees, nothing.

```
rm: remove regular file 'names.txt'? y
rm: cannot remove 'names.txt': No such file or directory
```

Windows has had no luck with its TAKEOWN command, even as administrator. Usually I can just go to the security settings and make myself owner. I tried the accesschk tool to see if maybe it had any clues, it can't even find the file. What do I do here?

Comment: Good question, and I'm glad you found a solution.  In the future though, consider putting "non-programming" WSL questions like this on either [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reboot. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete using Windows File Explorer. I'm sure it works. Go to your Ubuntu installation directory. It's probably `\\wsl$\Ubuntu`. The syntax is `\\wsl$\<DISTRIBUTION>` and again if you use Ubuntu on WSL so try `\\wsl$\Ubuntu`.

Paste `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` to your file explorer's top bar. Sorry I don't use Windows and I forgot how file explorer looks like and what "top bar" is called.

Comment: I tried explorer first. The file is in my main windows area, I just occasionally find success with WSL.

Comment: Oh so I think you can't delete Windows files from Linux maybe.

Comment: Try to reboot your machine.

Comment: well, you know what, rebooting actually did it. Or, the file is hidden forever. Hopefully the former. I guess it was cached somewhere. Weird.